# SSRS Field names change when table is added, how to resolve errors?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 to create SSRS reports on a SQL 2014 installation and I'm running into two issues that I hope someone here could shed some light on.

1) SSRS modifies the field name when a table with columns that match an existing column name when it is added to a data set. For example: Customer table has an ID and a Name field, Sales table has an ID and Product field). If start with just the Customer table I can add the ID field to the report. When I add the Sales table to the dataset the field name for the Customer ID field changes from 'ID' to 'Customer_ID' (to differentiate it from 'Sales_ID'). This causes an error with any references to 'ID' which I have to find and correct one-by-one.

Is there any way to make SSRS always use the Table_Field nomenclature for every table and field so this doesn't happen? Is there a short-cut method to get SSRS to update all references when a field name is changed by the query designer when a table is added?

2) Is there any way to get SSRS to sort Field names in the picklist in alpha order? It seems to default to table ordinal order which is difficult to search through in datasets with a lot of columns.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Alias your fields so that they are unique and SSRS never has a reason to change them.

Comment: By 'alias' do you mean updating every field in the query as 'AS' ? Such as SELECT ID AS Customer_ID from Customer?

Comment: yes.. that is correct.. you cannot have more than one column with the same name.. SQL server will.. but SSRS cannot.. so perhaps only alias the columns that are duplicates/ I.E. have the same name.. ? as your your second question.. not very clear.. but you can use interactive sorting

Comment: More detail on second question - by 'picklist' I mean the list of fields that popup when clicking on the 'blue list icon' in a textbox or the field list displayed under the dataset ion the Report Data Explorer. Both lists show the fields in their natural order (as the table was built). ID is the first column in the table so Customer_ID is first, then Customer_Company is after that, I'd like to see it as Customer_Company, then Customer_ID.

Comment: Persoanlly, I prefer aliasing any fields that aren't 100% clear on what they contain.  If I have a query containing customer data and contacts in two separate tables and the field containing the customer's name is simply called "NAME" while the contact name field is called "CONTACT", I'll alias both of them to keep things clear about what they are (CUSTOMER_NAME, CONTACT_NAME).  Little things like that can make supporting your reports much simpler.